# Mysql Match phrase against sentences with phrase

Tags: php, python, mysql

My situation is like this: 
I've got one table (`phrases`) with about 500,000 entries. Each entry is a phrase like:

```
Beating Around the Bush
Burst Your Bubble
Cry Wolf
Curiosity Killed The Cat
```

And I've got another table (`full_sen`) with 4000 entries,  where each entry is a sentence with a phrase in it.

I want to match `full_sen` table to find which sentences has phrases in them.

I need this to run frequently, as both tables will have new entries regularly, and I need something that can run fast.

The easiest query is to go over the 500k table and do a `LIKE %phrase%` search 
 against `full_sen` table, but that takes forever...

I don't mind incorporating PHP or Python if that would help; it does not have to be just a query.

```
full_sen    CREATE TABLE `full_sen` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `sku` varchar(21) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `full_sen_sku_670bbe26026365f4_uniq` (`sku`),
 KEY `full_sen_e8701ad4` (`user_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `full_sen_user_id_295adcd84efdd880_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5232 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

phrases CREATE TABLE `phrases` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `serial_number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `status_number` smallint(5) unsigned,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `serial_number` (`serial_number`),
 KEY `phrases_status_number_5f42a821_uniq` (`status_number`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=632144 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin
```

Name and Title are the fields I'm talking about.

Thanks.

Comment: update your work(code or query) which you have done

Comment: Please show the exact table definitions so that we can see the columns' length and the data types (post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`).

Comment: @binarus , POSTED

Comment: Please format code as code. Nobody is able to read that messy text ...

Comment: @binarus, done. Name and Title are the fields I'm talking about.

Comment: So you really want to check if `title` is contained in `name`, but `name` (being `VARCHAR(50)`) is shorter than `title` (being `VARCHAR(250)`)?

Comment: Every time you add (or remove or alter) a record in one table, you'll have to do a full scan of the other table to update the results. I don't see any way around this. You can perhaps shorten the scan by considering only records where ``LENGTH( full_sen.name ) >= LENGTH( phrases.title)`` but at the end of the day, MySQL can't really optimize this any further.

Comment: @Binarus, correct. yes it is allowed to be longer, but in most cases it is shorter than name.

Comment: @kmoser, Yes, of course I will need to run it again, that is not my issue, I just don't want each run to take forever. what you suggested doesn't shortens it enough unfortunately.

Comment: @IsaacDvory, my only other suggestion would be to  split up the processing among several instances of MySQL (e.g. replicated copies), each on a separate CPU (and/or physical machine, depending on what hardware you're using). This would probably require some additional coding, either in the form of, say, PHP scripts and/or stored procedures, so each MySQL instance knew which chunk of records to examine.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you could do to improve performance: Pre-computing and using indexes. Each of them will improve performance drastically, and you even can combine them. So let's have a look:

As you have already found out by yourself, the easiest solution is to loop through the `phrases` table and for each row do a `LIKE %phrase%` against the `full_sen` table (side note: you wrote `LIKE %sentence%`, but I think that was a typo - perhaps I'll edit your post later).

But actually, there is no need to do that.

Create a third table with name `phrase_sentence_pairs`, containing a column `ID` (this is just the row ID / primary key), a column `phrase_id` and a column `sentence_id`. `phrase_id` and `sentence_id` must be indexed (non-unique). Of course, at the begin you will have to fill that table with all data you already have according to the algorithm explained below. This may take a very long time, but it should not matter because it must be done *one time only*.

Now, when a new phrase is added to the `phrases` table, you only need to scan the whole `full_sen` table for that one phrase. Every time the phrase is included in a sentence, you add a new row to the `phrase_sentence_pairs` table so that `phrase_id` stores the `ID` of the new phrase from the `phrases` table and `sentence_id` stores the `ID` of the currently matching row of the `full_sen` table.

Likewise, when a new sentence is added to the `full_sen` table, you loop through the `phrases` table and for each row check if the phrase is contained in the new sentence. If yes, you add a new row to the `phrase_sentence_pairs` table so that `sentence_id` stores the `ID` of the new sentence from the `full_sen` table and `phrase_id` stores the ID of the currently matching row of the `phrases` table.

In terms of performance, this leads to the following situation:

You will not `SELECT` from the `phrases` and `full_sen` tables directly any more. Instead, for example, when you want to find all sentences for a given phrase, you first get the `ID` of that phrase from the `phrases` table and then select all records from the `phrase_sentence_pairs` table where the `phrase_id` matches.

The opposite action (fetch all phrases to a certain sentence) works in the same way.

Selecting from the `phrase_sentence_pairs` table will be lightning fast compared to what you had before. This is mainly because the database is now comparing numbers instead of partial-matching strings, and (more important) because this `SELECT` can be done using indexes.

On the other hand, inserting will be slower. But the overall performance gain will still be drastic:

Let's assume that the time the `SELECT` from the `phrase_sentence_pairs`  takes is negligible (this assumption is OK in this context), so we won't take it into account further. With your previous version, you had to do a `LIKE` string comparison for `500K * 4K` records every time you were selecting.

In contrast, you now have to do a `LIKE` string comparison on `4K` records when inserting a new phrase (which means a factor of 500K (!) in terms of rows which have to be scanned), and on `500K` records when inserting a new sentence (which means a factor of `4K` in terms of rows which have to be scanned).

Even if we take into account that we now have to write to two tables instead of one when inserting a phrase or sentence, and that writing to indexed columns of course is slower than writing to non-indexed columns, I think this is a very good deal.

If inserting is still not fast enough, there is another trick which could drastically improve the scanning speed. But before I elaborate on this, please first try my suggestions above and report the performance gain (best by adding it at the end of your question).

As a final note, please be aware that an `UPDATE` to the `phrases` or `full_sen` table must cause nearly the same code to be run as an `INSERT`, and that you must run appropriate code after a `DELETE` to the `phrases` or `full_sen` table.